# Is it possible to have markup in the Subject line using Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Example:

```
var mailOptions = {
  subject: 'Brand<sup>md</sup>' // Subject line
};
```

This subject line is obviously a string. So the generated emails subject line is `Brand<sup>md</sup>`.

Is there a way to generate the subject line via HTML?

I can't find any resolutions via Nodemailer's documentation. https://community.nodemailer.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible

Email `subject` can't be bold italic or dashed